# Why should i use google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I attended a recent analytics conference and it was beaten into everyone that anyone capturing analytics data should be using google tag manager.

I understood that it was of primary value to those wanting to make changes/maintenance, without access to the code.

Since I'm a developer, we already define our analytics tracking code in one spot, for the entire site.

What are the benefits of using it for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would get a better response and discussion by asking it in either the [Google Plus - Google Tag Manager Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/104865292981489764063) (lots of devs, even Google's main GTM devs) or on the [Google Tag Manager forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/tag-manager).